# Init touch by UITapGestureRecognizer's -locationInView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, gesture, touches

I use UITapGestureRecognizer on a tableView for -endEditing after -textFieldDidBeginEditing. First I want to make -endEditing and then perform this touch on tableView's element. How can I do it right way?

```
#pragma mark - Text Field Delegate

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(finishEditing:)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

- (void)finishEditing:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self saveName];
}
```

Comment: Can you be clearer about what it is that you are asking?

Comment: @Ian MacDonald Look, I have UITextField at the top of UITableView. When I begin editing text then I place UITapGestureRecognizer on the my tableView for send -endEditing to dismiss keyboard and save changes. Here is the most interesting: I need to implement cell's action after all of the above! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `cancelsTouchesInView` to false will pass the touches through to the view.

> When this property is true (the default) and the receiver recognizes
>   its gesture, the touches of that gesture that are pending are not
>   delivered to the view and previously delivered touches are cancelled
>   through a touchesCancelled:withEvent: message sent to the view. If a
>   gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if the value of
>   this property is false, the view receives all touches in the
>   multi-touch sequence.

See the reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView)